# resolved Jumi code is replaced when re-editing an article in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, jumi

I did following in order to include php code into Joomla:

1. writing a php application with jumi as:

   ```
   <?php echo '<p>Hallo Welt</p>'; ?>
   ```
2. include following code in the target article, where the previous code should be included:

   ```
   {jumi [*1]}
   ```

this worked so far.
But, when i try to edit the article again using the wyiwyg editor, the editor take the resolved formatting, means

Hallo Welt

and the original code get replaced {jumi [*1]}

this is get very problematic when the code is dynamic!

does somebody has a solution for this issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sourcerer plugging for including php script into an article, does not cause this overriding of source code by the displayed result, that's why I was forced to stop using jumi in favor of sourcerer.

Switching to raw mode is unfortunately not an option, since this would increase the effort of other authors who are supervising the platform and typing articles, especially when those are not so familiar with plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

No It's a common problem, no worries.

There are several hack you can do to avoid this.

1. Save the text in one file and every time edit the file and after copy and paste in Joomla.
2. When you edit the file, just edit from the source.
3. Use an alternative editor which is already in source mode like [RokPad](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokpad)
4. Check Plugin Manager > Editor - TinyMCE > Entity Encoding = raw

Comment: thank u for ur answer! since this is a commun problem, do u know some other plugins for php which don't cause that issue?

Comment: I've got it. Any way your answer helped me to stop searching fexing the problem using jumi :)